# Create and download PDF using html2pdf with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html2pdf

I'm doing the backend for a web application and I'm using the html2pdf class (http://html2pdf.fr/) to create a PDF file with existing data out of my database.

My frontend developer says he can not use that "stream" i deliver with the API using angular. I use the ->Output('D') method to provide the file.

Does anybody know how to use this class to download PDF files with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the data for a PDF file, use `responseType: "arraybuffer"`:

```
  var config = { responseType: "arraybuffer" };

  vm.fetch = function() {
    $http.get(url, config).then(function(response) {
      vm.result = "SUCCESS";
      vm.length = response.data.byteLength + " bytes";
      var blob = new Blob([response.data],
                          {type: "application/pdf"});
      vm.data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    });
  };
});
```

Convert the data to blob url and use a download button:

```
  <a download="{{name}}.pdf" xd-href="data">
      <button>Download data</button>
  </a>
```

`xd-href` Directive

```
app.module("myApp").directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XtlrB6Gtin0pH2CFxjH?p=preview) downloads `http://demo.html2pdf.fr/examples/exemple07.php`